# How to set up automatic deployment to Kubernetes from Docker registry

Tags: docker, kubernetes, continuous-integration, continuous-deployment

So many CICD tools use a git trigger to start the pipeline, but I want to use a new image upload to Docker registry. I have my own self-hosted Docker registry. Whenever a new image is pushed to the registry, I want to then automatically deploy that image into a workload in Kubernetes. It seems like this would be simple enough, but so far I'm coming up short.

It seems like it *might* be possible, but I'd like to know whether it is before I spend too much time on it.

The sequence of events would be:

1. A new image is pushed to the Docker registry
2. Either the registry calls a webhook or some external process polls the registry and discovers the image
3. Based on the base image name, the CICD pipeline updates a specific workload in Kubernetes to pull the new image

A couple of other conditions: the CICD tool has to be self-hosted. I want everything to be self-contained within a VPC, so there would be no traffic leaving the network containing the registry, the CD tool, and the Kubernetes cluster.

Has anyone set up something like this or has actual knowledge of how to do so?

Comment: Try flux - https://medium.com/@m.k.joerg/gitops-weave-flux-in-detail-77ce36945646

Comment: Thanks, James, I'll check it out.

Comment: See my article for a full sample: GitHub Actions - Reliza Hub (my tool) - ArgoCD - https://itnext.io/building-kubernetes-cicd-pipeline-with-github-actions-argocd-and-reliza-hub-e7120b9be870

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like the perfect job for [Flux](https://github.com/fluxcd/flux).

[image: flux]

There are a handful of other tools you can try:

- [Werf](https://werf.io/)
- [Skaffold](https://skaffold.dev/docs/)
- [Faros](https://github.com/pusher/faros)
- [JenkinxX](https://jenkins-x.io/)

✌️

Comment: I've been looking at flux all day. It looks like it needs a git account just to install. It also seems to need git for a release. Maybe I'm missing something.

Comment: Hmm it actually has a mode where it looks at the git repo for Kubernetes manifest and another mode where it looks at container releases in a registry. You can just use the second.  Can you elaborate need a git account to install?

Comment: I asked one of the developers, and here's what he said: "You can't use Flux just for image updates, Git is at the core of everything Flux does. Any changes on the cluster must go via Git."

Comment: That's the way they'd like to market it. aka GitOps. It doesn't mean that you can't use other functionality.

Comment: I never could get it to work, but I'll mark this as the answer.